# Windows 10 right-click in Windows Explorer broken

Tags: windows-10-preview

I use the SHIFT + F10 keyboard shortcut a lot, in Windows Explorer, to access the right-click context menu. I'm running Windows 10 Build 14332, and it's not working anymore. It's a fresh install from last night. It also wasn't working on my previous Version 1511 RTM install, which I still have available.

Has anyone else come across this problem? Is there a work-around or solution?

Comment: Does <shift>+<f10> do something else instead? Or nothing at all?

Comment: It just does nothing at all, in Windows Explorer. Still works in other apps.